# Duplicate char when searching through apps

Tags: ubuntu-gnome, gnome-panel

When I press Meta and then start typing to look for an app, the first letter is written twice.For example, if I type *"**f**irefox"*, the search bar will display *"**ff**irefox"*. I can manually press backspace after the first typed char, thus removing the 2nd unwanted ***f***, but it is quite annoying... has anyone experienced this issue before or has any tip on how can I fix it?
https://i.stack.imgur.com/cfsFJ.jpg

Thanks ❤️

(Running Ubuntu 22.04)

Comment: Does this happen only in the Activities input? What happens if you do the same in the terminal window or in a browser's search bar?

Comment: @FedKad Yes, only in the Activities input

Answer (score 2):

The culprit was the *Dash to Dock* extension. Disabling the setting "Show overview on startup" as someone suggested me here https://redd.it/zc59ql/ solved it